# How to configuration of nuclide for react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

Today I have two issue.

**One :**

I start npm server its successfully start, But there doesn't get barcode. So that I can't check my App with expo app or not at runtime check to change in js file.

Can you help how to get again barcode so that i can check at runtime.

**Second :**

I can't understand how to configuration in nuclide + ATOM, and How can run iOS or Android App using nuclide. Can you help to configuration of nuclide.

**Please see below SS. How To RUN iOS or Android.**

[image]